# javascript onclick link inside an iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

I have this link inside my iframe:

```
echo '<a href="#" onclick=\'javascript:window.href.location = "http://google.ca";\'>Click Here</a>';
```

but when I click on it, it doesnt work...anyone know why? When I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: reason you are not just using the link as a link?

Answer (score 2):

`window.href.location` is wrong

```
window.location.href
```

[MDN window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

also the javascript: label is useless.

```
onclick=\'window.location.href = "http://google.ca";\'
```

Comment: on my onclick still does not work...this link is inside an iframe